# Prevent duplicate windows/popups in x11

Tags: linux, thunderbird, xorg, kwin

For a very long time Thunderbird has had the issue of creating endless duplicates of the primary password prompt on start until you enter the password, and I don't know when anyone gets around to fixing it. This is annoying if you have Thunderbird in auto-start and don't always immediately want to read your emails on launch.

I need some kind of workaround to fix this. The taskbar clutter is really bothering me.

I'm thinking perhaps a script that detects when a duplicate prompt is created and immediately closes it. Running an entire looping daemon in the background just for that seems like overkill though. Maybe this can be done with a kwin script? (I'm using KDE Plasma.)

I don't know how to write Kwin scripts though, and have no real idea how to best begin solving this issue.

Comment: How have you set Thunderbird to start ?

Comment: .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart